# How to use chunk processing with Spring Batch?

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

I'm using Spring Batch for the first time. I tried some examples and read through documentation. But I have still questions:

- Can I skip one phase in chunk oriented processing? For example: I fetch data from database, process it and determine, that I need more, can I skip write phase and execute next step's read phase? Should I use Tasklet instead?
- How to implement a conditional flow?

Thank you very much,
Florian

Comment: I'm confused. Why did I get a down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Skip chunks** simply by throwing an exception that has been declared as "skippable exception". You can do it as follows:

```
<step id="step1">
   <tasklet>
      <chunk reader="reader" writer="writer"
             commit-interval="10" skip-limit="10">
         <skippable-exception-classes>
            <include class="com.myapp.batch.MyException"/>
         </skippable-exception-classes>
      </chunk>
   </tasklet>
</step>
```

**Conditional flow** can easily be implemented deciding on the `ExitStatus` of a step-execution:

```
<job id="job">
    <step id="step1" parent="s1">
        <next on="*" to="stepB" />
        <next on="FAILED" to="stepC" />
    </step>
    <step id="stepB" parent="s2" next="stepC" />
    <step id="stepC" parent="s3" />
</job>
```

Read the **documentation** to gain deeper knowledge on these topics: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

Comment: Thank you! I have one question left: How can I pass parameters between steps?

Comment: @FlorianMozart http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#passingDataToFutureSteps